# How to show many layouts from one activity

Tags: android, android-activity, layout

I have a main screen with 10-11 button.
whenever I will click one button it will take me to a list view where each list item
contains a image button and an image view.And image button will play a sound.
How can I simply achieve that? 
Fragments? /CustomListView? 
or I will just make 10-11 activity's defining different layouts for each item?

here is what i want
[activity with buttons](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/85071933/layout-208-030918.png)

[Activity when one button is pressed](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/85071933/layout-2015-0sadasd8-08-030618.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to.create 10-11 activities, Use Fragments and An Activity for Adding and Replacing those Fragments..
Also,  you can create a method that takes song Name as parameter, call that method when each ListItem is clicked and pass the name of Sound/Song to.play to that method.

```
void playSound(String songName)
{
 // codes that play song goes here 
}
When ListItem is clicked, do switch
List.setOnItemClickListener(new     OnItemClickListener()
@Override 
public void onitemClick()
{
switch(position)
{
 case 0: 
 playSound("SoundName")
 break;

}
}
);
```

Comment: Well that makes sense, can you please provide an full example on this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you have typical list view<->detail view (which is actually another list view) situation here.

In this case go with Fragments.

Here is official tutorial on Fragments

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

And here is one from Vogella

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html